# Mysql returning incorrect bigint result by one, very strange error

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, bigint

I really don't know what is going on here. I have a database table that looks like this:

[image]

With this data:

[image]

When I run this query `SELECT * FROM game WHERE id = 4` in phpmyadmin I get back this result as expected:

[image]

But when I make this query on it through a rest api (where gameId = 4)

```
var query = connection.query("SELECT * FROM game WHERE id = ? ",[game.gameId],function(err,rows){
```

I get this result

[image]

Where adminId for some reason has been subtracted by one. I really haven't a clue what is going on. I have tried dropping the table and setting it back up, has anyone experienced this before? Or know what is wrong? It's pretty frustrating! Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The maximum integer JavaScript can safely represent is [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER), which is 2^53 - 1. Your value is greater than that, which is causing some bits to be lost.

node-mysql has `supportBigNumbers` and `bigNumberStrings` options that parse `BIGINT`s as strings.

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
                            supportBigNumbers: true,
                            bigNumberStrings: true
                 });
```

Comment: Wow, I can't thank you enough! Excellent help thank you.