# create a foreach with an mysql result

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to check profiles with SteamID's. For that I got SteamID64's from my database, now I try to check every ID.

Basically it should set the SteamID64 from the database into an var, doing the code (easy example `console.log(steamidvar);`) and repeat it until there are no more SteamID64's left.

Thats a bit of a code I'm using:

```
con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    con.query("SELECT SteamID64 FROM Users", function (err, result, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(result);
    });
```

Thats the output I get:

```
[ RowDataPacket { SteamID64: 765611xxxxxxxxxxx },
  RowDataPacket { SteamID64: 765611xxxxxxxxxxx } ]
```

So everything is kinda working, but I need to get them in a while (don't know if its called like that, I'm used to it in php), so that the var resultsteamid is the SteamID64.

```
var account_id = new SteamID(resultsteamid);
```

My code rn: https://pastebin.com/raw/pUxnfjbR

Comment: If `result` contains the list of ids you want, why make a query for each? After `console.log(result)` do `var steamIds = result.map(r => new SteamID(r.RowDataPacket.SteamID64));`...

Comment: @HereticMonkey maybe I understood that wrong, but I want to repeat something until I have nothing left. So if I have 10 SteamID's then, for each SteamID this same procedure should happen until there are no more left.

Comment: That's not clear from the question at all...

Comment: Yeah, I gave an php example because I understand that :D

But do you still have a solution for this?

Comment: No, because I don't understand the question. Please [edit] your question with all of the requirements.

Comment: I did that and also added a piece of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see from the `console.log` that the `result` is just an array of rows. Javascript has quite a number of ways to iterate over an array. You've specified that you want each steamID to go in a variable "resultsteamid", so `for..of` or any array helper will assist you here:

**for..of**

```
con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  con.query("SELECT SteamID64 FROM Users", function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    for(let row of rows) {
      let resultsteamid = row.SteamID64;
      let account_id = new SteamID(resultsteamid);
      //use account_id however you want
    }
  });
});
```

**forEach**

```
con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  con.query("SELECT SteamID64 FROM Users", function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    rows.forEach(function(row) {
      let resultsteamid = row.SteamID64;
      let account_id = new SteamID(resultsteamid);
      //use account_id however you want
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Thats what I wanted :D
Unfortunately I get an Type Error if I want use "let account_id = new SteamID(resultsteamid);

Comment: You're welcome! Type Error is a very very wide class of error, when telling about an error it's extremely helpful to post the actual error message, that way we can know what went wrong

Comment: Oh yeah, sure: https://pastebin.com/raw/dzJVPquQ
The resultsteamid in my console is also yellow, maybe that could be the problem?
/root/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

TypeError: input.match is not a function

Comment: Sorry, I can't view pastebin links on this network, but I just meant the error message (not the stack trace) which should be short enough to stick here or edit into your question

Comment: @Schmaniel The SteamIDs are probably too big for JavaScript to represent correctly. I think you'll need to pull them differently, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28759036/mysql-returning-incorrect-bigint-result-by-one-very-strange-error)

Comment: oh yeah, that is working now :D

But actually the forEach is still not working how it should be.
rows.forEach( (row) => {
            var account_id = new SteamID(`${row.SteamID64}`);

            csgo.requestPlayersProfile(account_id, function(data) {
                console.log(data); }); });
This is causing two quick request and I'm only getting one player and then it starts again

Comment: @Schmaniel i think it'd be a lot easier to put this new problem in a new question so you can put all the relevant code and more people will see it

Answer (score 2):

You can just use an Interval in javascript:

```js
setInterval(()=>{
  console.log("CHECK THE MYSQL DATA")
}, 60000)
```

This bit of code will just run every minute (60,000 ms).

A better way to do it will be to define the variable with a namespace so you can also cancel it if you want.

```js
const checkData = setInterval(()=>{
  console.log("CHECK THE MYSQL DATA")
}, 60000);

// Then when you want to cancel it:
clearInterval(checkData);
```

- [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Comment: That makes sense and is pretty simple :)

But I actually have more problems with the while function (idk the name of it, but could maybe be foreach too) to get the SteamID's in a var, it can be only one or tow, but sometimes there are hunderes of ID's in the database...

Comment: could you explain the workflow without any code. just what is the process that is supposed to happen? I'm not completely following you.

Comment: I want to create a steam bot that checks the csgo player profiles.
All of the SteamID's are in my database, thats the code so far:  https://pastebin.com/raw/pUxnfjbR 
So the Bot should check every SteamID that comes out of the mysql SELECT.
I hope this is a bit more clear :)